# React: display element on hover (touch) but prevent initial click within div

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

This is a similar question to others on here, but I haven't found a question or answer that properly matches my scenario (yet).

I have a site that uses `:hover` CSS in a couple of places to reveal an *interactive* overlay with clickable elements (buttons, etc) in the overlay. This works great on desktop: user hovers to see more info and can then choose to click buttons, or not. On mobile the user needs to click the element to trigger the hover pseudo-class and reveal the overlay. This is actually the behaviour I want, but has the issue that if there is a button directly underneath where the user clicked it is triggered immediately.

The effect I'm after is that for mobile/touch, the user first has to click the element to reveal the overlay, then they can click on buttons, etc, within the element. Desktop should continue to work with hover as it does now.

I don't think this behaviour can be achieved with CSS alone, although that would be ideal of course...

Example code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-epunjm?file=src/App.js

```
// App.js
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="content">
        Hello StackBlitz!
      </div>
      <div className="overlay">
        <span>This is overlay</span>
        <button onClick={() => alert("clicked!")}>BUTTON</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// style.css
div {
  font-family: Lato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.content {
  background: orange;
}

div.content, div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.overlay {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

div.container:hover div.overlay {
  display: inherit;
}
```

EDIT:

Many thanks to Onkar Ruikar for his answer. I took inspiration from his ideas but ended up using focus state (using tab index), and disabling pointer events for the overlay contents until the overlay has focus. This requires detecting when device has touch using a media query and may not be totally reliable but should serve my needs.

Working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dupeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On single tap, at button location, following events are fired:

```
content   touchStart
container touchStart   //here CSS rule brings overlay forth
content   touchEnd
container touchEnd

container mouseEnter
overlay   mouseEnter
button    mouseEnter
button    clicked        // the button gets clicked in same tap! 
overlay   clicked
container clicked
```

As all these things happen on single touch, so there isn't much we can do in CSS.
Here is one solution using javascript: [codesandbox demo](https://gerny.csb.app/hoverTouch.html)

```js
let show = () => overlay.style.display = 'inherit';
let hide = () => overlay.style.display = 'none';

// for pointer devices ----------------------
container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => show());
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => hide());


// for touch devices -----------------------
content.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  show()
  // break the event chain that leads to click
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});

// there is no reliable mouseleave event in touch devices
// so need to provide close button
hideMe.addEventListener('click', () => hide());

// mimicking mouseleave, not ideal though
(function() {
  /* this doesn't work properly
  overlay.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
  })*/

  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.stopPropagation());
  document.addEventListener('click', () => hide());
})();
```

```css
div {
  font-family: Lato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.content {
  background: orange;
}

div.content,
div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.overlay {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

button {
  user-select: none;
}

#hideMe {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  right: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="content" class="content">Hello StackBlitz!</div>
    <div id="overlay" class="overlay">
      <span>This is overlay</span>
      <button onclick='alert("clicked!")'>
          BUTTON
        </button>
      <div id="hideMe">X</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Old solution**

```css
div {
  font-family: Lato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

div.content {
  background: orange;
}

div.content,
div.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.overlay {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

div.container:hover div.overlay {
  display: inherit;
}

button {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="flag=true">
  <div id="root">
    <div class="container" ontouchend="flag=false">
      <div class="content">Hello StackBlitz!</div>
      <div class="overlay">
        <span>This is overlay</span>
        <button 
          ontouchend="flag=true; event.stopPropagation()"
          onclick='if(flag) alert("clicked!")'>
            BUTTON
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When we tap on button location for the first time, touch event is fired on container but not on the button. It fires only when we actually tap on the button. So we set the flag accordingly. As browsers on desktops doesn't fire touch events this doesn't affect the original behavior in desktop browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very inventive! However, I am trying to make a React component where the content of the overlay isn't known in advance and is passed to the component (might contain multiple buttons, etc). Can you think of a way to handle this where the button itself doesn't need to be involved (ie. achieve separation of concerns)?

Comment: Added a new solution. I've tried to mimic mouseleave on touch device. But there is no mouseleave on touch devices, so I think adding a close button is a more sensible option.

Comment: Ended up going with a different approach (see my edit to OP), but thanks for your help

Comment: `:focus-within` is a nice idea. But on Safari it takes 3 taps to get the alert. First one brings up overlay, second gives it green border, third tap shows the alert. Ipad also has track pad, that means there is a mouse pointer, which brings up overlay on hover but needs extra click to get it the focus-within then next click shows the alert.